# Encrypting Stored Procedures Securely

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there anyway to securely encrypt a stored procedure?

I've read all about WITH ENCRYPTION and how you might as well not bother as it's child's play to break it.

I can't seem to find any other possibilities here but wondering if I've missed something?

Comment: AFAIK There is no 100% secure method. If you pass your code to someone else DB instance then he could decrypt it (matter of time). Of course you could try to obfuscate code and encrypt using CLR but I don't think it will stop potential user.

Comment: Don't give people permission to view stored procedure definitions -- that helps a lot. Failing that, don't put anything *in* stored procedures that is worth encrypting in the first place. Secrets should be kept and encrypted through the various `ENCRYPTBY` functions, and again only made available to accounts with permission. In that vein, I suppose you could package the stored procedure as an encrypted `EXEC` statement that you decrypt and execute on demand, but again, that assumes you have business logic worth encrypting, which smacks of security through obscurity to begin with.

Comment: If you are asking how to securely prevent privileged users from viewing T-SQL stored procedure source, the answer is you can't. To protect intellectual property, your license agreement is the protection.